# Determine item that was clicked with context menu

Tags: autodesk-forge

In this post is desribed a way to customize context menu:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/customize-viewer-context-menu

But is there any way to determine that item was exactly right-clicked? I want to add action for clicked item (not selected) in context menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look further down that blog post you will find the following code snippet to find the dbid(s) of the item being right clicked on:

```
async buildMenu( event, status ) {
   // Do hitTest to get dbIds
   const viewport = this.viewer.container.getBoundingClientRect();
   const canvasX = event.clientX - viewport.left;
   const canvasY = event.clientY - viewport.top;

   const result = this.viewer.impl.hitTest( canvasX, canvasY, false );
```

Hopes this answers your question and do let me know if there's anything more I can help with.

Comment: No problem. Take care :)

Comment: Also, as suggestion (if you are from Forge team): pass click event into "target" callback (in case to determine if Ctrl is pressed, for example). Now I have to override "addCallbackToMenuItem" method in ContextMenu to do that